# Views inside a NavigationDrawer are not clickable

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-navigation

I have a DrawerLayout that contains a ScrollView and inside that ScrollView I have a  LinearLayout that its children are clickable:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ...>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="240dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout ...
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout ...
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="navigationDrawerItemOnClick">
...
```

Inside Activity, I have a method to open drawerLayout as below:

```
public void navigationImageButtonOnClick(View v) {
    drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
```

Problem is that when I click on items, the only things happen is that navigation drawer closes and `navigationDrawerItemOnClick` will never be called.

I am not using ActionBar and drawerToggle.

Comment: Have you tried to attach onClickListener inside code? e.g. findViewById(R.id.ll_id).setOnClickListener(.... ?

Comment: I Found the problem. I should put navigation layout at the end of NavigationDrawer not at the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Put your custom layout at the end of the root drawer layout.

The Custom view should be the last child of Root Navigation Drawer Layout.

For reference, check the link : http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/05/android-custom-navigation-drawer-not.html